# Filter array of tuples in swift

Tags: arrays, filter, swift

I have an array of named tuples.

And I would like to apply a filter on this array depending the value of an element of my array of tuples

```
typealias Section = (sectionName : String, sectionInputs : [Input])

var defaultSectionsData : [Section]

var found = sectionsData.filter($0.sectionName == myString)
```

But I've this error:

> Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: .filter{$0.sectionName == myString}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A closure must be defined between brackets:

```
var found = sectionsData.filter({$0.sectionName == myString})
// or equivalently
var found = sectionsData.filter {$0.sectionName == myString}
```

Comment: could you also do var found = sectionsData.filter {$0.0 == myString}

Comment: @Honey -- Yes you can