# How do I filter on an array of objects in Swift?

Tags: swift, filter

Hi I have an array of type Book objects and I'm trying to return all the Books filtered by the `tags` attribute. For example

```
var books = [

(title = "The Da Vinci Code", tags = "Religion, Mystery, Europe"), 
(title = "The Girl With the Dragon Tatoo", tags = "Psychology, Mystery, Thriller"), 
(title = "Freakonomics", tags = "Economics, non-fiction, Psychology")

}]
```

and I want to find the books associated with the tags `Psychology`, `(title = "The Girl With the Dragon Tatoo", tag = "Psychology, Mystery, Thriller")` and `(title = "Freakonomics", tags = "Economics, non-fiction, Psychology")`, how would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Array of \[AnyObject\] in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709723/filter-array-of-anyobject-in-swift)

Comment: Start by using a proper data model. Define a struct with a title property and a property for tags that is an array of strings. Using a tuple and having your tags as a single string is a poor choice of data model and makes all of your tasks more difficult.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter array of tuples in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862096/filter-array-of-tuples-in-swift)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I quickly did this to help out, if someone can improve that's fine I'm just trying to help.

I made a struct for the books

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let tag: [String]
}
```

Created an array of those

```
var books: [Book] = []
```

Which is empty.

I created a new object for each book and appended to books

```
let dv = Book(title: "The Da Vinci Code", tag: ["Religion","Mystery", "Europe"])
books.append(dv)
let gdt = Book(title: "The Girl With the Dragon Tatoo", tag: ["Psychology","Mystery", "Thriller"])
books.append(gdt)
let fn = Book(title: "Freakonomics", tag: ["Economics","non-fiction", "Psychology"])
books.append(fn)
```

So you've three objects in the books array now.
Try to check with

```
print (books.count)
```

Now you want to filter for Psychology books.
I filtered the array for tags of Psychology - are filters ok for you?

```
let filtered = books.filter{ $0.tag.contains("Psychology") } 
filtered.forEach { print($0) }
```

Which prints the objects with your two Psychology books

> Book(title: "The Girl With the Dragon Tatoo", tag: ["Psychology",
>   "Mystery", "Thriller"])
>
> Book(title: "Freakonomics", tag: ["Economics", "non-fiction",
>   "Psychology"])

Comment: Don't forget that Swift it is a type inferred language there is no need to explicitly declare your types 99% of the time. Btw you should declare the struct properties as constants

Comment: I believe he is saying we can use the form let dv = Book(title: "The Da Vinci Code", tag: ["Religion","Mystery", "Europe"])
 for each book

Comment: and `struct Book {
    let title: String
    let tag: [String]
}`

Comment: And you can also initialize your books as follow `let books =
[( "The Da Vinci Code",              ["Religion","Mystery", "Europe"]),
 ( "The Girl With the Dragon Tatoo", ["Psychology","Mystery", "Thriller"]),
 ("Freakonomics",                    ["Economics","non-fiction", "Psychology"])].map(Book.init)`

Comment: Yes, I just did the above as I thought it might be easier for a beginner.

Comment: Note that your `filter count == 1` is very bad it will iterate the whole array even if it finds the element at the first index. change it to `books.filter{ $0.tag.contains( "Psychology")}` which will provide an early exit in case it matches it

Comment: Thanks, this is more feedback than I've had in 14 months of working as a developer

Comment: "there is no need to explicitly declare your types 99% of the time" But it's a good habit, actually, because explicit type declarations can greatly improve compilation times.

Comment: Pedantic comment: if you make the tags a `Set` instead of an `Array`, the `contain` call will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Representing the books as an array of tuples with named parameters title and tags for book title and tags respectively.

```
let books:[(title:String, tags:String)] = [

    (title: "The Da Vinci Code", tags: "Religion, Mystery, Europe"),
    (title: "The Girl With the Dragon Tatoo", tags: "Psychology, Mystery, Thriller"),
    (title: "Freakonomics", tags: "Economics, non-fiction, Psychology")

]
```

You want to search for tag `Psychology`

```
let searchedTag = "Psychology"
```

We can use `filter` function to filter out the items in the books array that only contains the tag we are looking for.

```
let searchedBooks = books.filter{ $0.tags.split(separator: ",").map{ return $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) }.contains( searchedTag ) }

print(searchedBooks)
```

Inside the filter method, we have created an array of tag items from book tags using `split(separator: Character)` method. Next, using `map` function, we remove the leading and trailing whitespaces from each tag. Finally, using `.contains(element)` method, we test if the tag we are looking for is in this array. Only the tuples passing this test are returned and the others will be filtered out.

The result is:

> [(title: "The Girl With the Dragon Tatoo", tags: "Psychology, Mystery, Thriller"), 
>   (title: "Freakonomics", tags: "Economics, non-fiction, Psychology")]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more useful for lack of wrong typing situation.

```
books.filter( { $0.tag.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
```