# How to get all tuples with specific value in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

Say I have an array of tuples like this:

```
var countryData = [
(country:"Australia", item:"GDP", Year:"2019", dataValue:"1.434 trillion"),
(country:"Australia", item:"CPI", Year:"2019", dataValue:"6401.0"),
(country:"Australia", item:"Inflation", Year:"2019", dataValue:"1.61%"),
(country:"Brazil",   item:"GDP", Year:"2019", dataValue:"$1.868 trillion"),
...
(country:"Zimbabwe", item:"Inflation", Year:"2019", dataValue:"255.29%"),
]
```

I want to create an instance variable to **get all the tuples containing "Australia"**. I'm assuming I have to use a for loop and contain function but my swift isn't that good and I can't get it to work. Or any suggestions if this isn't the best way to go about this is also appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of tuples in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862096/filter-array-of-tuples-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! You can use for loop for this. The other way is the filter operator

**filter operator way** gives you an ability to filter an array of any type by specific criteria.

```
let neededList = countryData.filter { $0.country == "Australia" }
```

**For loop way**

```
var result: [(country: String, item: String, Year: String, dataValue: String)] = []

for item in countryData {
    if item.country == "Australia" {
        result.append(item)
    }
}

print(result)
```

Comment: How is this different from what I have already posted? ;)

Comment: Sry I didn't see. Now I added for loop answer too

Comment: Maybe adding a better method would have been nice. Using a `for in` loop in this scenario is kinda outdated and should be avoided.

Comment: @Frankenstein You didn't consider searching for duplicates yourself?

Comment: Perfect, precisely what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LarvusKoji No problem. Mark this answer if it was helpful for you! It is my first answer here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the higher order `filter` method. Here's how:

```
let australiaData = countryData.filter { $0.country == "Australia" }
```